# automatically determine best filter size to use in keras CNN Conv2D layers

Tags: keras

```python
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5),
                  padding='same',
                  data_format='channels_last',
                  input_shape=input_shape))


model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

This is what my current keras model looks like, which is completely borrowed from [here](https://yashk2810.github.io/Applying-Convolutional-Neural-Network-on-the-MNIST-dataset/).

My question has two parts,
1. How do I automatically determine whether to use         `model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))` or `model.add(Conv2D(32, (5,5)))` or `model.add(Conv2D(32, (4,4)))` ?
2. except the first line of the model, If I change the rest of the conv2D(64, (3,3)) models to (5,5) I get `negative dimension obtained by subtracting 5 from 3) . why is that?

I looked at these two questions : [Selecting number of strides and filters in CNN (Keras)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46065445/selecting-number-of-strides-and-filters-in-cnn-keras) and [Conv2D layer output shape in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46174757/conv2d-layer-output-shape-in-keras)
according to them experimenting is the only way to find out, but I was wondering if there is an automatic way to do it.
Because there are so many parameters such as `value of dropout` , `kernel_size()` and then value of `Dense()` should it be 512/356 or how much is the best.

PS:
Running different models with different parameters is becoming computationally expensive, and comparing all these results is becoming another painful process.
My laptop has a 2GB nvidia graphic card with 5.0 compute capability.

Comment: this might help. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/12/31/keras-conv2d-and-convolutional-layers/

Comment: You might be interested in `Inception Network` architecture as it combines multiple sized filters in the same layer.

Answer (score 1):

1. The kernels dimensions are hyper parameters that you can automatically optimize using a number of strategies. [Here are a couple of tips for that](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html)
2. The output height/width of a convolutional layer follows the equation `size = ((input_size - kernel_size) / stride) + 1`. So you're using too many convolutional layers for an image that is too small. At some point `size` will be negative and you can't have a negative shaped output

Comment: thank you. so should I leave the rest of the conv2d layers as (3,3)?

Comment: also is there any rule around `        model.add(Dense(512))
` choosing the optimum  value here ^.

Comment: Also if I changed model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
 to (3,3) it again complains. how do I fixed that ? thanks